# C# webbrowser control (executing all javascripts associated with form)

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to auto submit form using webbrowser control. I am using the following code to submit"

```
currentElement.InvokeMember("submit");
```

Now this methods works fine. But sometimes a form may have some javascript function that is called on button click at the time of submission. So let's say if a form has some button image called "Submit" and when a user presses it, a javascript function somefunction() is called and then form is submitted.

Problem is when I use the above method InvokeMember then it only submits the form and doesn't execute associated scripts (in this case somefunction()) and I have to manually write code

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("somefunction");
```

But this requires that I know before hand if there is some function. Is there any way I submit form and it will automatically run all associated javascript?

And I don't know button name or ID either which is clicked by user to submit form. Because in some cases it may not even have ID or name for e.g.

```
<span class="btn" onclick="somefunction()">
<img style="cursor:pointer" title="Submit" alt="Submit" src="http://stackoverflow.com/imagesbutton.png?2012">
<div id="s" style=""></div>
</span>
```

Comment: Oof. That `<span onClick>` example that you gave is going to make this a really tough problem to solve in the general case. In your `<span onClick>` example, I assume that typing stuff into the form and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't work, either. If the browser can't spot the submit button, I don't give your wrapper good odds...

Comment: You can simulate a click on anything but you can't determine this action eventually end up doing a submit. So, the answer to the question "Is there any way I submit form and it will automatically run all associated javascript?" is yes, provided you know where to click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I have messed around with the WebBrowser control, but I used to make it jump through hoops for me. I've come across this issue in the past.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/60924/Using-WebBrowser-Document-InvokeScript-to-mess-aro

When you get a `Form` object, take the string out of the `OnSubmit` and run this to execute it before submitting the form:

```
object[] codeString = {"myObject.setVariable(0);"};
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval",codeString);
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name or id of the image tag you can use

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button").InvokeMember("click");
```

or

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByName("button").InvokeMember("click");
```

to call the associate function in javascript